# No project showing up in Eclipse even though I imported

Tags: eclipse

I have been working on a project in Eclipse. All of a sudden, I don't my project. I have no idea what happened. The source code is not checked into any source code control system.

I tried to re-import the workspace, it doesn't complain. But it doesn't show anything. Attached is the screen shot of my Eclipse after importing the project.

[image: Eclipse project]

Comment: Click on Window -> Show View -> PackageExplorer

Comment: You are the saviour Abi